# Rails doing change in devise view but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for my authentication.So when your logs in there is a message or popup comes **Signed in successfully** .So i want to apply my jquery such that message should disappear after 3 sec or 5 sec ..But I try to search that message in my devise views it was not there ..Although i do some research i got that message but it was there in **devise.en.yml** but i can't apply my jquery over there so can any one help me in finding that message or to how get that message

Answer (score 0):

The popup you talk about must be a flash message. These messages are generated from the Devise Library files. Please refer to the `Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController create method` .

I hope you can write javascript to control this messages if you can find the div that loads these messages in your views

Comment: can you elaborate more or can you give me an example

Comment: You need to find the HTML DOM element in which this message appears and then you can manipulate it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

@Aniket you have to find in your layouts folder

`flash`

it will be wrapped in a div and you can apply your javascript for the div.

Alternatively you can make use of the **google chrome developer console** to inspect the flash message and identify the dom element to apply the jQuery function.

Comment: in my layout folder i have application.html.erb and there is no flash messages set